# TradingView {{close}} does not work for alerts, Plain Text

Tags: pine-script, plaintext, alerts

I would like to make https://www.tradingview.com/script/whJATyGU-UT-Bot/ this bot more useful but there are some problems that I have faced, I hope you can help me.

The code is written on Plain Text.

I have modified the code like below, (just added two lines of codes in order to create alerts)

```
study(title="VET Bot", overlay = true)

SOURCE = input(hlc3)
RSILENGTH = input(14, title = "RSI LENGTH")
RSICENTERLINE = input(52, title = "RSI CENTER LINE")
MACDFASTLENGTH = input(7, title = "MACD FAST LENGTH")
MACDSLOWLENGTH = input(12, title = "MACD SLOW LENGTH")
MACDSIGNALSMOOTHING = input(12, title = "MACD SIGNAL SMOOTHING")

a = input(1, title = "Key Vaule")
SmoothK = input(3)
SmoothD = input(3)
LengthRSI = input(14)
LengthStoch = input(14)
RSISource = input(close) 
c = input(9, title="ATR Period")

xATR = atr(c)
nLoss = a * xATR
xATRTrailingStop = iff(close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close - nLoss),
                    iff(close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close + nLoss), 
                        iff(close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), close - nLoss, close + nLoss)))
pos =   iff(close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), 1,
        iff(close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), -1, nz(pos[1], 0))) 

color = pos == -1 ? red: pos == 1 ? green : blue 
ema= ema(close,1)
above = crossover(ema,xATRTrailingStop )
below = crossover(xATRTrailingStop,ema)
buy = close > xATRTrailingStop and above 
sell = close < xATRTrailingStop and below
barbuy = close > xATRTrailingStop 
barsell = close < xATRTrailingStop 

alertcondition(buy, title='Al', message = 'Al')
alertcondition(sell, title='Sat', message = 'Sat')
plotshape(buy, title = "Al", text = 'Al', style = shape.labelup, location = location.belowbar, color= green,textcolor = white, transp = 0, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(sell, title = "Sat", text = 'Sat', style = shape.labeldown, location = location.abovebar, color= red,textcolor = white, transp = 0, size = size.tiny)

barcolor(barbuy? green:na)
barcolor(barsell? red:na)
```

In order to use the alerts I have created, I have to change the alert condition on the alert screen like attached image.

[image]

My problem starts here, in general when I use default alerts on TradingView I am able to use the {{close}} variable for reaching the close price of the bar however, if I use the script I have edited I cannot use it and the messages seems like that;

> (COINBASE:BTCUSD, m1), price =   {{close}}

m1 is the timeframe of the alert, which is 1 minute in that case.

Does anyone have an idea how can I use the {{close}} variable or any ideas for reaching the price?

I also tried to change message part of the alert on code like below, but then on the alert screen I am having an error.

Best regards,

```
alertcondition(buy, title='Al', message = 'Al @' + tostring(close))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`{{close}}` works only with `@version=4`
However, once you put `@version=4` at top of your code, you will get lots of errors since some of the your code isn't recognized by `@version=4`. You're gonna have to convert those into `@version=4`.